# Order Button on each row of a table

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a table of items and I would like to place an order button at the end of the table. The button would then take user to "order.php". Where based on the "Picture ID" they would then order the selected item. I've had a look at similar questions online however haven't been able to get it working with what I currently have.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    echo "<table>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>". $row["Picture ID"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>". $row["name"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>". $row["doc"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>". $row["width"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>". $row["height"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>". $row["price"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>". $row["description"]."</td>\n";
        echo "<td> <form action='order.php' method='post'> <input type='button' name='id' value= ></form>"
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</table>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the picture id as hidden input text and use the "submit" type for the button:

```php
echo "<td> <form action='order.php' method='post'> <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row["Picture ID"] . "'/> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Buy'/></form>"
```

In order.php you can get the Picture ID from $_POST:

```php
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) { // submit button was pressed
  echo 'Picture ID: ' . $_POST['id'];
}
```

Make sure to escape the $_POST['id'] properly when using it in SQL queries.